# prestodb get user identity in a stored procedure

Tags: presto

I configured presto (version 0.206) to use user/pass authentication and added a custom procedure that receives 2 string args.
Is there a way to get the identity/principal of the user that ran the query in the procedure?

thank you

Comment: It would be good to share the code you already have. Other than that, try adding `ConnectorSession session` as a first parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/blob/d7f1f2cdf3c6d58ca0a10e598996fb08f64a9cd8/presto-main/src/main/java/io/prestosql/execution/CallTask.java#L171), any parameter can be `ConnectorSession`.  You can get the `Identity` from the `ConnectorSession`, and it contains the current user name and the authentication principal.  The authentication principal may not be present when there are views in a SQL query, but in the case of a procedure there can not be a view, so it should always be present. For security reasons, none of the built in authentication implementations store the authentication credentials.